# MacPro on network slowing down Mother-in Law on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, osx-lion, airport, appletv

At home I have a cable modem / router / WiFI providing highspeed internet.  The default WiFi that comes with the router caused nothing but grief with iTunes and our Apple TV's so I added my Airport base station to extend the LAN network on the cable modem router.

My problem:  My mother-in-law is hardwired dorect to the cable model router and my MacPro is plugged into the Airport which is plugged into the cable router.  The mother-in-law complains that my computer 'slows down' her computer.  She is my mother-in-law and older so trying to get a better explaination of 'slows down' is next to impossible.

All she does on that system is play Facebook games which is the source of the grief.  Her solution is to unplug the Airport base station which 'speeds things up'.  My MacPro is running the latest version of the OS with VirusBarrier and I am not running any server or filesharing apps etc. so I can't see how my system is 'slowing' her system.

Before I addded the Airport base station I had my MacPro connected directly and she had the same complaint so I am guessing that the Airport is not part of the problem.

I think she's crazy and am tired of having to come home to my computer and our Wifi network down because her slow Farmville performance.  Before I put my foot down on this I want to make sure my machine is actually not part of this problem (if it is actually a problem).

Any ideas / suggesetions to start to troubleshoot this?

Comment: mother-in-law is owned by macPro! yea!

Comment: Normaly this would bring me happiness but having my wifi / high speed down on a regular basis is a negative net benifit.

Comment: She's right. You should not use your shiny computer because it's messing up with the sluggish PC she has. Also, why the heck are you doing anything on your computer when she needs all the bandwidth for her bandwidth intensive FarmVille?! Are you out of your mind?! You are doing it on purpose. =))

Comment: With plug-n-play objects, there are easy way of disconnecting or connecting devices. For you there is a simple way of doing that (actually there are two options): unplug mother-in-law, remove yourself and wife. :) [I know, I'm mean, but I couldn't help it]

Answer (score 0):

It is actually a very strange problem. I have noticed that if i downlaod something intesnse on my notebook then my mother-in-laws computer does actaully slow down. But if she downloads then mine is OK.  I am not yanking you chain this is fact.. and its pissing me off as well.

There is one difference though. I have a nice new i5 Dell and she has a piece of rubbish Acer that I have to fix every 6 wseeks.

just plug her directly into the modem of the internet and all problems solved.

Comment: She is plugged in direct.  The issue seems to be that my system sitting idle on the network bogs down her machine.  Now that I think of it I should plug her into the Airport and see if that fixes it.

Comment: well if she is direct (lan cable) into the modem that is connected to dsl/adsl then there is no chance your computer is `slowing` her down, period. she must have some issue with flash.. i know farmville get really slow with lots of cows, pigs and haybails

Comment: I am ready to shut my computer off one day and ask her if it slowed down again.  I think it's her machine but I would like to somehow prove it or at least eliminate my system as a suspect.

Comment: borrow a usb 3g/hsdpa dongle and let her top it up. she will have full bandwidth to her self.. if it still slows down.. time for format or something like that

Answer (score 0):

Is your Mac system running any app like Skype for example?

Skype when it's idle tends to act as a gateway and "Shares" your connection with other people that might need some more band with.

I know at least that is how Skype works in Windows environments, not entirely sure in Mac.

But in my office we have 8 pcs and my mac and usually my skype is eating a lot of band with even when I'm not using it. 
I've installed an app to monitor the traffic in my network and Outlook and Skype in Mac were the two things that were using more band with, even when idle.